# Using axios in angular

Tags: angular, http, axios

I am learning angular and I was wondering if it is fine to use axios to make http requests to server.
This works but I am confused if it is a bad practise to use axios like this in angular. I wonder if I can continue doing this or use HttpClient and subscriber model. Are there any downsides to using this approach, most of the tutoriols I find are using httpclient and subscriber model, while this seems easier to understand especially for beginners like me.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Student } from './models/Student';
import { students } from './models/StudentList';
import axios from 'axios';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class StudentService {
    students: Student[] = students;

    // adding a new student
    public addStudent(name: string) {
        const addStudent = async (name: string) => {
            try {
                const response = await axios({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://localhost:8080/student/add',
                    data: {
                        'name': name
                    }
                });
                if (response.status === 201) {
                    alert('student added');
                }
            }
            catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }


        }
        addStudent(name);
    }

    // getting list of all the students
    public getAllStudents(): Student[] {
        const studentList: Student[] = [];
        const getAllStudentsAxios = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await axios({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: 'http://localhost:8080/student/all'
                });
                // console.log(response.data);
                for (let responseObject of response.data) {
                    const student: Student = new Student();
                    student.id = responseObject.id;
                    student.name = responseObject.name;
                    studentList.push(student);

                }
            }
            catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }

        }

        getAllStudentsAxios();
        return studentList;
    }


    // getting student by id
    public getStudentById(id: number): Student {
        
        const student : Student = new Student();

        const getStudentByIdAxios = async () => {
            try {
                const url = 'http://localhost:8080/student/' + id;
                const response = await axios({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: url
                });
                student.id = response.data.id;
                student.name = response.data.name;
            }
            catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        }

        getStudentByIdAxios();
        return student;
    }

    // get courses registered by student


    // student registering a course
    public registerCourse(student_id: Number, course_id: number): void {
        alert('course registered ' + student_id + course_id);
    }


    public submitReview(student_id: Number, course_id: Number, rating: Number, review: string) {
        alert(student_id + ' ' + rating + ' ' + review + ' ' + course_id);
    }

    public deleteCourse(student_id: Number, course_id: Number) {
        alert(student_id + ' ' + course_id);
    }

    constructor() { }
}
```

Comment: angular.io is your friend

Comment: angular.io uses httpclient and subscribtion model, what I want to know is if its fine to use this way instead of that ?

Comment: yes follow angular.io.

Answer (score 2):

using axios in angular is totally fine but httpClient would be best practice.

Comment: For a project migrating from AngularJS to Angular, using Axios is a good intermediate step to get the application working, without having to rewrite the logic and introducing observables. AngularJS and Axios work very similar, and a lot of code can be reused, maybe adding '.data' here and there.

Answer (score 1):

Using Axios in Angular definitely possible but it's not a common pratice and is not recommanded.

Angular internals rely on you using the `HttpClient` (for `ApplicationRef.isStable` among others).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to follow Angular best practices, you should consider using HttpClient and the observable pattern. Here's a quick example of how you might rewrite your getAllStudents method using HttpClient:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Student } from './models/Student';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StudentService {
  private apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/student';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public getAllStudents(): Observable<Student[]> {
    return this.http.get<Student[]>(`${this.apiUrl}/all`);
  }

  // Other methods can be similarly refactored
}
```